# Bash script to remove leading white spaces from files names

Tags: bash, fish

So I have a bunch of files like:

```
 Aaron Lewis - Country Boy.cdg
 Aaron Lewis - Country Boy.mp3
 Adele - Rolling In The Deep.cdg
 Adele - Rolling In The Deep.mp3
 Adele - Set Fire To The Rain.cdg
 Adele - Set Fire To The Rain.mp3
 Band Perry - Better Dig Two.cdg
 Band Perry - Better Dig Two.mp3
 Band Perry - Pioneer.cdg
 Band Perry - Pioneer.mp3
```

and I need to have the leading whitespace removed in bash or fish script.

Comment: Do you mean you're renaming the files to not have the white space in front, or are these file names stored in a text file and you need to process them?

Comment: I want to rename files to not have the white space in front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the leading white space char in the file names you provided you can use:

```
 IFS=$'\n'
 for f in $(find . -type f -name ' *')
 do 
     mv $f ${f/\.\/ /\.\/}
 done
```

This:

- changes the IFS to only be newline characters; this way it does not choke on the whitespaces in the file names.
- finds all files starting with a whitespace in the current directory.
- moves each file to a file name without the leading whitespace, using `bash` substring substitution.

Comment: That did it! I always forget about IFS. That was what was killing my own script. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work, returns "mv: '...' and '...' are the same file".
I suspect this only works in the current directory, not recursively.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in \ * ; do
  mv "$x" `echo "$x" | sed "s/^ +//"`
done
```

This is quick and dirty.

Comment: no go. I get this `usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory`

Comment: Interesting. I ran this in a bash shell and it worked for me. I just did it again to be sure: I copy and pasted those lines exactly to my shell terminal and it renamed my files that started with space to files that don't start with space. I'm running Fedora 17 Linux. What flavor of Unix are you running?

Answer (score 0):

`cat <file> | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'`

should do the trick. Capture stdout and write to a file.

Comment: Im looking to remove the leading spaces in file names. Not file content. Good try though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sed` for this. Just use `bash` string function:

```
for file in /path/to/files/*; 
    do mv "$file" "${file# *}"; 
done
```